# 2 react version dependencies in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to run npm install, but I am getting the following error:

`The package react@15.2.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!`

This is because 2 or more of my packages depend on varying versions of react. I've heard that using npm 3+ fixes this, but for work reasons I need to use npm 2.x. Not sure how to resolve this dependency issue. Any tips?